# Unable to find php.ini file while trying to install composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I just downloaded php for windows from http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6 ( 
VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe (2015-Oct-29 21:57:41) and zip file of size 20.22MB).

Then I added the php to my PATH variable. So the PATH variable looks like this:

`...; D:\MySoftwares\php\PHP5_6`

The PHP5_6 directory contains the php.exe and other files.

I am trying to install composer, but I get this error in screenshot:
[image]

I followed various stack overflow posts and they seem to suggest uncommenting the line that says `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in file php.ini

Unfortunately for me, I can not see any php.ini file in the PHP5_6 directory. I see php.ini-production and php.ini-development files.(I uncommented these lines in both, but no results)

So how do I go ahead to install composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose either `php.ini-production` or `php.ini-development` and rename it to `php.ini`.
Those are default configurations, with suggested settings for each kind of environment.
As it seems you are in development, so probably best to take the php.ini-development.

Comment: Yeah i renamed php.ini-production to php.ini and it worked. Was wondering where is it documented.

Comment: I don't know where that would be documented, there are some guides explaining what todo, but otherwise this is all I found:

 http://php.net/manual/de/migration53.ini.php

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/newinis

Comment: Thanks. This works and I am sure that it will help other users also who are looking to install composer on windows.